# AngularJS and Cordova function for download and write local file, but writing doesnt'work

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I made a html5 application for android with apache cordova and angularjs. In this app, i have a map with geojson data. Data is on a distant server, i want to join it, get json data and write it into a file in /android/data/com.domain.name directory ("normal" way). The GET part is ok, but the file is not writing... i test application in usb device (phone) and i don't now how to log that. Do you see what's wrong in my code or how i can log the emulation ?

That's my code :

```
/* ONCLICK */
$scope.reloadMap = function() {

/* test online */
    if(navigator.onLine) {

        /* url */
        var url = "http://www.domain.com/API/map.js";

        /* download file - distant */
        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);

                /* write file - local */
                function fail(error) {
                    console.log(error.code);
                }
                function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                    writer.write(data);
                }
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
                }
                function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile("data/com.domain.name/data/map.js", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
                }
                function requestFS() {
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
                }
                /* write function OK */
                requestFS();
        }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }
}
```

I cut errors treatment for a more readable code.

the /android/res/xml/config.xml (after compil) of my app is like

```
<widget id="" version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <author></author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4500" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
</widget>
```

no directory is created, so what's wrong ?

Comment: i put "window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;" for a test in chromium and i get "LocalFileSystem is not defined" error

Comment: This is "window.PERSISTENT" and not "LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT".
For your problem, be sure to wait for the "deviceready" event before the requestFileSystem.